# WooCommerce dynamic thumbnail images for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a function that sets the thumbnail for variable products. At the moment I would have to go into the backend and apply the image manually but I want something more dynamic.

For example lets say I have a variable product called Lamp inside there are three child products. Each child product is the same but vary in colour (blue, green, yellow). Now what I want is the variable product to have same image as the first variation inside but if a colour filter of yellow is applied to the shop page I want to get the image for that variation and display that instead for the variable thumbnail.

I have almost created this functionality but there is an issue both if statement can be true for different products and I end up with multiple thumbnails for the product.

How can I improve this function?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'set_product_image', 10);

function set_product_image() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ){
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

            $product_colour = strtolower( $variation->get_attribute('colour') );

            $filter_colour = $_GET['filter_colour'];

            if( $product_colour == $filter_colour){
                echo $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );

            }else if( $product_colour != $filter_colour ){
                // echo $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );

            }
        }
    }else if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo $product->get_image( array(300, 300) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
    // image of first variation
    $default_image = '';
    foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ){            
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        $product_colour = strtolower( $variation->get_attribute('colour') );
        // set image of first variation
        if( $default_image == '' ){
            $default_image = $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );
        }
        $filter_colour = $_GET['filter_colour'];

        if( $product_colour == $filter_colour){
            // if filter applied, echo and return
            echo $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );
            return;
        }
    }
    // filter not applied, return default image
    echo $default_image ;
}
```

Comment: Just created something similar myself although yours uses less code, I'll try it out